# Generating Scatter Points Alogrithm

Tags: swift, math, sprite-kit, logic, point

I am making a game which spawns scattered `x` number of points. All Points have a constant radius of `w`

The points must follow these rules:

- Points may not overlap other points
- Points must be spread apart so that each point is at least `DISTANCE` away from any other points.

Can you please list an efficient algorithm to execute this?

I am also making this game in Swift Sprite-Kit. So if you know some Sprite-Kit, you can implement it in your answer, otherwise if you do not know Swift or Sprite-Kit you can explain in words.

Comment: What do you mean by `All Points have a constant radius of w`? Are points actually spheres?

Comment: yes all points are spheres

Answer (score 1):

Your two constraints are equivalent. It means the distance between any two points must be at least `max(w, DISTANCE)`.

The easiest way is to generate random points and check the minimum distance to previous points. If the constraint is not fulfilled, just generate a new point. You can speed up the distance checking with a simple grid (put points in the grid cells and then just check the cells that may contain overlapping points).